# Why can't I edit view or edit custom data fields that include multiple choice options?

Tags: custom-fields, multiple-choice

I'm having problems editing custom fields with multiple choice options. I have created custom fields which display in preview mode.
[image]

But the custom fields don't appear when I try to Edit Multiple Choice Options. (The "Add Option" button works on this screen."
[image]
What have I done wrong?

Also, my only resources (besides StackExchange)for learning about profiles and custom names is https://docs.civicrm.org/user/. What other sources should I consult before posting questions here?
CiviCRM 5.38.0 on Wordpress

Comment: This problem persists. Yesterday I created a new Custom Field Set and entered multiple choice custom names with no problem. Today I find that I can't edit the multiple choice options because they are not visible in the edit window. The behaviour of the multiple choice option seems top have changed overnight. I also found that I cannot create a new multiple choice name in that field set because the field for entering the new options aren't appearing (but they were appearing yesterday).

Comment: To add data to the symptoms of this problem - when the fields are first created, they appear normally in the edit box but if you close the edit box and reopen, all you get is the window with nothing in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the editing link in a new tab or a new window works.  Thanks to Pradeep Nayak for the suggestion and to Joe Bedford for pursuing this.

Answer (score 2):

Could you clear CiviCRM cache and try again? Or try to open the options in new tab or window

Comment: I have cleared the CiviCRM cache and my browser cache. The problem persists: I can preview the multiple-choice fields but the window for editing multiple choice options is empty. I think I've made a mistake in creating the Custom Names.